# use anaconda python with pycharm

Tags: pycharm, anaconda

is it a good idea to use anaconda python as an interpreter for pycharm? can I then use both pycharm and anaconda?

I am having trouble with setting up the interpreter for anaconda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can definitely use Anaconda with PyCharm. Whether it's a good idea or not, it depends on your and your team preferences (if you're not working on a solo project).

#### How Anaconda works on PyCharm

By default, PyCharm tries to force you to follow the good practice of creating a new environment per project that you're working on (instead of using Anaconda's base environment). This means that when you're opening a folder for the first time, or creating a new project in PyCharm, it expects you to create a new environment or configure which of your already existing environments you want to use for that project.

### Adding a New Anaconda Environment to PyCharm

**Original documentation from PyCharm:** [PyCharm: Configure a Conda virtual environment](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/conda-support-creating-conda-virtual-environment.html)

I recommend following Pycharm's documentation to register a new Anaconda Environment to PyCharm, but here's my take on trying to explain the steps involved:

The following screenshots go through the process of adding a new Python interpreter (you can think of the interpreter as being the same as a new Anaconda environment) to PyCharm:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

The above print screen shows you how to register the `base` environment. However, you could use one of your already existing environments, by referencing them instead. By default, Anaconda registers every environment you create inside `/opt/anaconda3/envs/` (or `"%USERPROFILE%\Anaconda3\envs\"` if you're on Windows).

So for example, to register an existing environment named `dev`, you could set the Python interpreter path to `/opt/anaconda3/envs/dev/bin/python` (or `"%USERPROFILE%\Anaconda3\envs\dev\bin\python.exe"` if you're on Windows) instead of the original `/opt/anaconda3/bin/python`.

**Note:** if you don't know where Anaconda was installed or want to see all your Conda environments, you can open up a new console window (Command Prompt on Windows) and execute the following command:

```
conda info --envs
```

This command returns a table with each of your existing Anaconda environments, alongside their base paths.

[image]

After registering the Interpreter, you'll be able to select and set it as the default interpreter for your project so that the next you open this project on Pycharm, it'll be set to it already.

Comment: I mean, just for this lengthy reply, you deserve a medal!